# Start Mode = Alwaysrunning however after server restart app pool is disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, application-pool, windows-server-2012-r2

net 4.5.2, IIS 8 and windows server 2012 R2

Start mode is alwaysrunning at app pool config

However after server restart i see that app pool is disabled

Here below my web.config file (changed public token keys in case of any vulnerability)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="60"/>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=sadasdasdas"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=asdasdasdsa"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=asdasdasda"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <trust level="Full"/>
    <sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </sanitizer>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error404.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error404.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
    <pages validateRequest="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="true" enableSessionState="true" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"/>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true"/>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="asdasdasdas" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.6.0" newVersion="1.4.6.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="asdasdasdas" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please check event log to see what error caused IIS to disable this pool for fast failures.